# Missing Data Updates

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, clickonce, missing-data

I am having a problem with data not updating on the CRM at my wife's office.

Scenario:

1. User loads the app.
2. Data from the DB populates the master view.
3. User opens edit screen.
4. Data is populated for the correct detail item.
5. User changes a value (on any field).
6. The save button becomes active with
   the data change.
7. The user clicks on save.
8. The data is refreshed on the edit screen (to prove the update took) and the original data is restored to the edit screen.
9. The save button is disabled.
10. Looking at the master data grid,
    behind the edit screen, the data
    appears to be updated.
11. Close the edit screen, the new data
     is still visible in the master view.
12. Click on refresh and the master data
     reverts to the original content.

All changes are lost.

If I run the exact same scenario on my dev network, the database IS updated.

So what is different between the two environments?  There is a domain at the office.  I'm using SQL Authentication so it shouldn't matter.  I'm running a Win2003 EE with MS SQL 2005 EE VM for my test DB server, which mimics the office DB server.  I use backups of the production DB to populate my dev DB.  I have double-checked the SQL user permissions.  There are no errors in the Event Viewer or in the SQL logs on the DB server.  All workstations are Win7 Ent.  I run x64 at home, while the office machines are x86.  Walking through the code on my machine doesn't provide any insight because everything works in my dev environment.

The app has been around since December 2008.  I do monthly updates at a minimum.
ClickOnce deployment.

I need to run SQL Profiler to gatehr more info.  Beyond that, I'm clueless.  What is really happening?  Why does it work in dev and not in prod?  Any suggestions on how to track this down?

Thx,

Ivan

Answer (score 0):

after starting the application, but just before save is clicked, rename the table in sql server management studio.  See if the application throws an error about the table not existing. If you don't get an error, then C# isn't trying to update the database.  if you get the error rename the table back, add a trigger on the table to write to a log table, restart the application, and try the save.  check in the log table, did it insert anything? go from there.

Comment: When I renamed the table the data update threw an exception.  So the app is talking to the DB, but not updated the records.  That's a bit of info I didn't have this morning.  Time to dive back into it and follow-up on the trigger suggestion.  

Add'l suggestions welcome.

Thx